# Push Notification Get url on tap and display it in View Controller , iOS , Swift4.2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

My didReceiveRemoteNotification in App delegate is,

```
 private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

           print("UserInfo: \(userInfo)")

            switch application.applicationState {
            case .active:

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                if let title = userInfo["title"]
                {
                    content.title = title as! String
                }
                 content.userInfo = userInfo
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"rig", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                    if let getError = error {
                        print(getError.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            case .inactive:
                break
            case .background:
                break
            }
          }
```

And my response after push notification is,

```
 [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("content"): https://staging.travelsheriff.de, AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "Friend Request";
            title = "Dave has  sent you friend request";
        };
        category = "https://staging.travelsheriff.de";
        sound = default;
    }, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.url"): https://staging.travelsheriff.de]
```

I have to store "content" as string and pass it to my view controller (as url) to display. How could I perform this....

Answer (score 1):

In order to get url from push notification, Try this in your App delegate 
(that will save the content(url) from push notification response.)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let content: UNNotificationContent = response.notification.request.content
        let userInfo = content.userInfo
        if let url = userInfo["content"] as? String{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("url"), object: url)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "urlNotification")
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourPushViewController") as! yourPushViewController
            window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Then in your push view controller call in viewdidload like this,

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
          pushUrl()// this is function to call the notification url in web view 

        }
    func pushUrl() {
    let getPushURL = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "urlNotification") as? String
   if let url = URL(string: getPushURL) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                webView.load(request)
      }
    }
```

Comment: it worked fine, getting url and could show it in my pushviewcontroller. Thanks

Comment: is there any way I can show this url on Notification alert as a hyperlink????
on clicking that hyperlink open a web View.(This part of showing url on webview is done) the only thing is I have no idea if I can show hyperlink text on remote notification.

Answer (score 0):

In your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` Method,

```
if let url = userInfo["category"] as? String{
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("url"), object: url)

}
```

In your ViewController add this line in viewDidLoad

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.gotUrl(string:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "url"), object: nil)
```

then implement this method :

```
 @objc func gotUrl(string : String){
    print(string)
}
```

if you want to save it then in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` Method

```
if let url = userInfo["category"] as? String{
   UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "url")

    }
```

then retreive :

```
if let url =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "url") as? String {
        print(url)
    }
```

Comment: could u please suggest how can I call function to show in view controller mean how to present vc

Comment: I tried to do the same in view controller but it’s showing error in completion handler.